# Banana vs Brazilian Nuts Radiation

Tags: radiation, estimation, biology, unit-conversion

[Looking online](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_equivalent_dose) I can find that the BED (Banana Equivalent Dose) is around 0.1uSv, but Brazilian Nuts can have up to 444Bq/kg.

I know both of those foods are safe, I just wanted to understand how those units compare to each other, how much more radioactive is a Brazilian Nut compared to a Banana.

Comment: Do this question belong to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Isn't radiation physics?

Comment: This question is certainly on topic on [physics.se]. It might also be on topic on [chemistry.se], but as I am not very active there I don't feel qualified to make a definitive statement.

Comment: You can't convert directly these two quantities. However, you may try to reproduce the computations of the [banana equivalent dose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_equivalent_dose#Source_of_radioactivity), applying it to the Brazilian nuts.

Comment: And can this be done?

Comment: FYI: Saying that bananas are radioactive can be misleading. Bananas contain potassium, and a certain fraction of potassium is radioactive. You _need_ potassium in your diet. You will suffer health problems if you don't get enough. But your body does not store excess potassium. If you eat too much of it, you will literally piss the excess away. So, if you are not suffering from potassium deficiency, then eating bananas will not increase the amount of radioactivity in your body in the long run; and if you _are_ suffering potassium deficiency, then eating bananas will only improve your health.

Answer (score 1):

Answering directly to "I just wanted to understand how those units compare to each other":

You can't convert directly between Sievert (Sv) and Becquerel, since they represent different physical quantities.

Quoting the [definition of Sievert from the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert):

> 1 Sv = 1 joule/kilogram – a biological effect.
>   The sievert represents the equivalent biological effect of the deposit of a joule of radiation energy in a kilogram of human tissue.

And quoting the [definition of Becquerel from the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Becquerel):

> One becquerel is defined as the activity of a quantity of radioactive material in which one nucleus decays per second.

So, 1 Bq = 1 s$^{-1}$.

Therefore, Sievert and Becquerel are distinct things.

Comment: So I would have to find out how much radioactive potassium there is per banana and get how much Bq this is? I just wanted to know something like "a banana 20x less radioactive than a Brazilian Nut"

Comment: To make the computation you would need to know which isotopes are the main source of radiation of a Brazilian Nut and in which relative quantities they are present. With this, you could compute the estimated biological effect per emitted radiation particle. My suggestion would be to follow the "Dose calculation" section of the Wikipedia of the banana equivalent dose page.